# Switch VARCHAR to DATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

I inherited a database that has a VARCHAR column that really should be a DATE. There's no checking on the form (I need to fix that) so dates constantly get entered as 2016-12-4 instead of 2016-12-04 and so forth.

I'm pretty sure there are historically a lot of bad dates, so I'm a little skeevy about just changing the data type to DATE, but I'm curious about what would be a good strategy for changing that?

Background: (I'm a front-end developer, not a DBA, so while I can get around in SQL I don't know what I don't know and I'm always afraid I'll make a mistake that corrupts the database).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str_to_date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to handle the conversion.

```
str_to_date('2016-12-4', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: That will work even for bad dates?

Comment: They're not bad, they're just not 0-padded.

Comment: Well, they're bad in that they sort wrong.

Comment: They sort wrong, because they're text, try `ORDER BY str_to_date(col, '%Y-%m-%d');`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Then given that, do you recommend I change the data type on the column or just leave it as is and use the `ORDER BY str_to_date` function?

Comment: Use the `date` type. It's faster to store, and index and things that work with `date` know they're getting a `date` -- (it's typed).

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT CAST('2016-12-4' AS DATE);` --> `2016-12-04`, so you don't need `str_to_date`.

I would add a new column for the date (`ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..`); `UPDATE` to set the new column.  Then manually fix any really messed up values.  Finally `DROP COLUMN` and `RENAME COLUMN`;

`ORDER BY` a `VARCHAR` that contains a date in it may lead wrong answers.  (Jan and Nov may get confused.)  Testing for specific dates may fail.  (Missing leading 0.)

And indexing the DATE column will make certain queries faster.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the VARCHAR column to an DATE column is also not a problem.

**Test table and data**

```
CREATE TABLE test.t1( `date_start` VARCHAR(20) ); 
INSERT INTO test.test1 VALUES('2016-1-5');
INSERT INTO test.test1 VALUES('2016-1-5');
INSERT INTO test.test1 VALUES('2016-12-5');
INSERT INTO test.test1 VALUES('2016-12-6');
```

**Select query result.**

```
SELECT * FROM test.test1

date_start  
------------
2016-1-5    
2016-1-5    
2016-12-5   
2016-12-6
```

**Change the column VARCHAR to DATE**

```
ALTER TABLE test.test1 CHANGE date_start date_start DATE NULL;
```

**Select query result.**

```
SELECT * FROM test.test1 

date_start  
------------
2016-01-05  
2016-01-05  
2016-12-05  
2016-12-06
```

Comment: Did you mean to repeat `date_start` in the ALTER statement?

Comment: @Robusto yes to change a column's type but not the name, CHANGE syntax still requires an old and new column name, even if they are the same. :

Comment: One thing to note: If the varchar values are not currently in a valid (mysql) format, like 'XXXX-XX-XX', then after the alter statement it will end up with all '0000-00-00'.

Comment: I needed to run this command first:
update {table} set {field} = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE({field}, '%m/%d/%y'),'%Y-%m-%d');

Comment: @RobertKoernke MySQL can directy convert during ALTER from VARCHAR to DATE if the data formats is in a [date format MySQLl supports](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html), generally this is in YYYY-MM-DD format.. You had DD-MM-YYYY format then yes you need to use a conversion..